# Ghostscript NetworkPrinter

Tags: c#, ghostscript, network-printers

I have some trouble with sending document to a network printer by Ghostscript.
I am using CMD:

```
gswin32c -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies=1 -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="\\spool\\\192.168.27.206\Brother" "C:\Users\Eindhoven\Documents\work\print\Test\Printing.pdf"
```

but it doesnt work(it shows window to choose printer - seems can't find it by network address), only if I use printerName(Brother MFC-J5320DW) instead of network Name(\192.168.27.206\Brother - I shared printer myself and trying to access it by my computer ip). 
Does anybody know what could be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript sends its output to a file, that's why the switch is called OutputFile.

IP addresses are not files.

In fact in this case you aren't even sending it to an IP address. You have specified the destination as a directory called spool (on the current drive) with a sub-directory called 192.168.27.206 and then into a file in that directory called Brother. Unless your printer has that directory on your directory mapped as a share, and is monitoring the directory for new files, there's no way its going to go to the printer.

You **might** be able to do this by creating a "Standard TCP/IP port" on your machine, then sending the file to that port, in the same way you could send it to LPT1:

Comment: And if my printer is shared in the network it has directory for files to print "\\192.168.27.206\Brother" is not true?

Comment: I have no idea how your printer works. I can tell you that unless you can write to a file, then Ghostscript will no be able to print to your printer. Writing to the spool directory is definitely insufficient.